# scrapy: Error downloading AND TypeError: to_bytes must receive a unicode, str or bytes object, got NoneType

Tags: python, proxy, scrapy

This is my first time using scrapy with proxies. When I test my code, an error occur, but I cannot find where my code wrong.

The pycharm told me that ERROR: Error downloading https://movie.douban.com/subject/25754848/reviews> and TypeError: to_bytes must receive a unicode, str or bytes object, got NoneType.

Here are the middleware codes.

```
import requests
import lxml
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from scrapy import signals

class ProxyMiddleware(object):

    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/get'
        r = requests.get(url)
        request.meta['proxy'] = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml").get_text()
```

Comments of the code: I have a proxies pool. When it runs, I can get different proxy ip and port like "113.122.136.41:808" from the address "http://127.0.0.1:5000/get"

Here are the errors and traceback list.

```
2017-04-16 10:20:06 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Error downloading <GET             
https://movie.douban.com/subject/25754848/reviews>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\empra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1299, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = result.throwExceptionIntoGenerator(g)
  File "C:\Users\empra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\twisted\python\failure.py", line 393, in throwExceptionIntoGenerator
    return g.throw(self.type, self.value, self.tb)
  File "C:\Users\empra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\middleware.py", line 43, in process_request
    defer.returnValue((yield download_func(request=request,spider=spider)))
  File "C:\Users\empra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\defer.py", line 45, in mustbe_deferred
    result = f(*args, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\empra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\handlers\__init__.py", line 65, in download_request
    return handler.download_request(request, spider)
  File "C:\Users\empra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\handlers\http11.py", line 61, in download_request
    return agent.download_request(request)
  File "C:\Users\empra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\handlers\http11.py", line 260, in download_request
    agent = self._get_agent(request, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\empra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\handlers\http11.py", line 240, in _get_agent
_, _, proxyHost, proxyPort, proxyParams = _parse(proxy)
  File "C:\Users\empra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\webclient.py", line 37, in _parse
    return _parsed_url_args(parsed)
  File "C:\Users\empra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\webclient.py", line 20, in _parsed_url_args
    host = b(parsed.hostname)
  File "C:\Users\empra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\webclient.py", line 17, in <lambda>
    b = lambda s: to_bytes(s, encoding='ascii')
  File "C:\Users\empra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\python.py", line 117, in to_bytes
'object, got %s' % type(text).__name__)
TypeError: to_bytes must receive a unicode, str or bytes object, got NoneType
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can tell you how to convert stream coming from url to unicode.

```
import requests
import urllib2
import lxml
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from scrapy import signals

class ProxyMiddleware(object):

    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/get'
        r = requests.urlib2.open(url).read()
        data=r.decode("utf-8")
        request.meta['proxy'] = BeautifulSoup(data, "lxml").get_text()
```